# Django Media files handling

Tags: django-templates, django-media

I have set:

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_in_pro")]
```

I have a directory media_in_pro in base directory of project and within this i have directory called **"profile"** like **"media_in_pro/profile/image.jpeg".** I have added in my urls  `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to `URL_PATTERS`.

My problem is when I try to access this image in template like this:

```
img src="{% media 'profile_image/profile.jpg' %}"
```

then it raises **TemplateSyntaxError** because of this **media**. It does not recognize **"media"** in img tag.While my static files are working fine and i have used same method for my static files. While i am using static in the same way without any problem. Can anyone help me in sorting this out?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to edit it like as you did? I often get this problem?

Comment: This is a good answer on how to format the code in your question [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1434964](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1434964)